# Stack items vertically in rows/columns instead of horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an html page and want to switch to scrolling and floating of the page. So within the body or a div I want a list of items. Every item should go under the previous unless the end of the div is touched, then it should go on the higher part and so on. So if there is to many to display it should give a horizontal sroll bar. Basically if you turn the screen 90 degrees you get what i want.

Schematically the items should go like this:

```
1  4  7  10
2  5  8  11
3  6  9  12
```

I've really no clue where I should start with this one. I don't know how to call this so searching for it is difficult.

I think I need to split up my problem in 2

```
- ordering the items so they go in the flow like in the scheme.
- scrolling horizontally.
```

Some direction in what css to use would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you forced to use a single `ul`, `ol`, or `dl`? And will you know how many items there are in advance?

Comment: no I'm not forced to use a singe ul, ol or dl. The amount of items are known in advance and will stay the same.

Comment: Oh wait, define in advance. I know it (server side) before the page loads. But it should be flexible for more/less items.

Comment: BAM!!! Answered :-) View secondary post.

Comment: Now it is even easier if you use, `column-count: 3` or set that dynamically to `n / 4` using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Must say, quite proud of this one

#### Example 1: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/LZqxm/4/ (100 items, small box)

#### Example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/LZqxm/5/ (1000 items, large box)

**All dynamically arranged, so any `width/height` `div` will work. Also, only limit on data would be around 78,400,000 items. (Which HTML would die from anyway).**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="ourWrap">
<div id="expander">
<ul id="data">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
       ...
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
</ul>    
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#ourWrap {
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    position:absolute;
}
ul {
    display:table-cell;  
}
li {
    list-style:none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    var dataRemap = [];
    var $cHeight = $('#data li:first-child').height();
    var $wHeight = $('#ourWrap').height();
    var colHeight = $wHeight/$cHeight;

    $( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
        dataRemap.push($(this).text());
    });

    $('#data').remove();

    var ul;
    $.each(dataRemap, function (index, value) {
        if(index % colHeight === 0) {
            $('#expander').append(ul);
            ul = $('<ul>');
        }
        var li = $('<li>').append(value);
        ul.append(li);
    });
    $('#expander').append(ul);
});
```

#### Example 1: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/LZqxm/4/

#### Example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/LZqxm/5/

---

#### So, what exactly is going on?

Took your single list of data, and backtracked into an array so **JS** can manipulate it easier.

Then I emptied the existing items in the `ul`.

Based on an `index` value of our `array`, and comparing the height of the `div` to the `height` of a `li` item, found out the total items that will fit into the `div` based on it's current `height`.

Then we used a quick script to append a new `ul` to the container for every `modulus` it encountered based on that equation.

### I told you this is not typically easy lol

Comment: Thanks a lot Nicholas, I need to implement this into my project, but as far as I can see now this is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for the effort!

Comment: Yeah, it was a pain in the ass lol. Hopefully it helps! Thanks for the accepted answer! With the existing code, you could just inject all of your data into a single list, and this will do the rest :-)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend  css **[columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns)**. See browser support **[here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)**.

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/apeCAniQ/1/edit)**

```
<ul class="col-2">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>

  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.col-2 {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}
```

Commonly, javascript libraries like Masonry, Isotope, and Packery are used for this behavior, since css columns are only supported in more recent browser versions.

### Base row count on height of parent, or set row count manually

Here's another option and I shimmed it with javascript to be more dynamic: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/apeCAniQ/14/edit)**

```
<!-- you can determine the row count according to this container's size -->
<!-- this element is otherwise unnecessary -->
<div class="container">

<ul class="wrap">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>

  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>

  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* raise this to increase row count! */
.container {
  height: 40px;
}

.wrap .col {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.my-class .item {
  display: block;
}
```

**JavaScript (with jQuery for simplicity):**

```
var $wrap = $('.wrap');
var $parent = $wrap.parent();
var $items = $wrap.children();

//set row count based on parent height
var rows = getRowCount($items, $parent);

//or set it manually here
//var rows = 2;

sets = [];
while ($items.length > 0) {
  sets.push($items.splice(0, rows));
}

sets.forEach(function(set, i) {
  $set = $(set);
  $set.addClass('item');
  $setLi = $('<li class="col"></li>');
  $setList = $('<ul></ul>');
  $setList.append($set);
  $setLi.append($setList);
  $wrap.append($setLi);
});

function getRowCount() {
  var rows = Math.floor($parent.height() / $items.height());
  return (rows) ? rows : 1;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will only make 2 columns. I need a set amount of rows, set by the height of the the div. And preferably flexible: more height more rows and vice versa.

Comment: @WillemdeJong hmm, it seems to me that the other answer and my update had the same idea in mind in regards to that. However, both solutions require wrapping sets of elements in an additional element, so that doesn't seem ideal either. Either way, you're having to do some kind of calculation.

Comment: @WillemdeJong Check out both answers and see what you think. I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure the only way you'll automate this as much as you want is to use one of the js libraries I recommended in my post.

Comment: Thanks for the references to the libraries. Fortunately I don't have to support older browsers. I think i need to make some javascript as well to calculate the rows based on the height.

Comment: Javascript provided :-)

Comment: @WillemdeJong I also updated my answer with a javascript solution. Don't forget to click accept on your favorite answer!

Comment: First column. 0,1,68,69,130,131,188,189,246,247... (fullscreen view. Looks like it's only interpreting a a few rows at a time to convert to columns)

Comment: @NicholasHazel because that's not the first column.

Comment: OHHHH! Ignore me. The bounding box was setup differently. The only problem is it will cascade further down instead of develop the scrollbar.

Comment: @NicholasHazel Yes, I used inline-block so that they would go underneath. This could easily be adapted with `table-cell`. Either approach has its issues.

Comment: Touche. Well, I believe this one is solved two ways. On to the next one! Well done mate :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Something like this ought to do the trick:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/YExUz/3/

**EDIT**: Also, just to show you it works fluidly based on the information you toss into the HTML, I added an extra row and extra col in the HTML.

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/YExUz/5/

Added a `border` so you can see the definition.

Does this seem to do what you want? Try copying and pasting the `ul`s and place as many as you'd like within the box.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="ourWrap">
<div class="expander">
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
</ul>    
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#ourWrap {
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    position:absolute;

}
.expander ul {
    display:table-cell;  
}
.expander li {
    list-style:none;
}
```

---

## Edit:

#### Based on your new info, you have two options if you want a `static div height` but the items to flow the way you're describing.

**Option 1**: Use a jQuery script to identify and recalculate the data based on div height.

**Option 2**: *"...You can sacrifice W3C web standards and use deprecated markup, you can live with markup that’s less than semantically logical, you can tolerate a mixture of presentation with content, you can say goodbye to browser compatibility, or you can use markup that’s heavy with attributes and styling that’s heavy with rules. Every road exacts a toll..."*

**Cited: http://alistapart.com/article/multicolumnlists**

Comment: I thought of basically the same thing. My version is a little different, but I don't think this is what he wants either. The issue is that you still have to calculate something (how many items to wrap). I don't think there is a pure css solution to the overall issue, so I think my suggestion of a js library is the way to go if it has to be super automated.

Comment: This is already a lot further I ever got. Just one thing to solve left. Yes I know I'm picky. Amount of rows should depend of the size of the div, so viewers will see more rows watching with maximized screen than when it is in a small window. But thanks a lot for putting me in the right direction Nicholas.

Comment: So, you don't want the size of the DIV reflecting the amount of rows...? But the other way around? For that calculation, you can't really get a single `ul` to start flowing in such a way without hard coding them in. This would be EASILY solvable with `jQuery` if you're open to using a script on top of this code. Let me know if you want an example.

Comment: You are too kind Nicholas, Jquery is used in the site, so no problem.

Comment: One second sir. Going to have to restructure the HTML, so I may just post a new **answer**.

Answer (score 1):

Incase this helps: More modern approach with CSS Grid:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Wow</li>
  <li>Awesome</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
  <li>Brilliant</li>
  <li>Wonderful</li>
  <li>OH MY GOD</li>
  <li>NEW COLUMN YES</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>What about</li>
  <li>only three items?</li>
  <li>Just one column!</li>
</ul>
```