# CSS - stack elements vertically - horizontally

Tags: css, html, css-float

Suppose I have a parent DIV with width 200px and I have 5 child DIV with width each 50px and float:left as style .. in this case, I expect 5th div to stack below 1st div....

Now, I want this to be done other way.. i.e. all elements first stack vertically one below other and when height is reached 100%, then remaining elements stack themselves in 2nd row and so on..

ex: say if I assign height 200px to parent div, then 5 element should stack in right of 1st element assuming all elements have height of 50px.

thanks.

Comment: Second @Hardy: it helps if you show us your code and include your attempts and research. At any rate, you should probably have a look at [CSS columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) (though [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) is shaky).

Comment: I recommend my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21355860/1435655